# Is it not possible to set expectations on a lazy property?

Tags: mockito, kotlin

The following test yields a `NullPointerException`. Is it not possible to set expectations on a lazy property?

```
class GarbTest {
    @Test
    fun xx(){
        val aa = Mockito.mock(AA::class.java)
        Mockito.`when`(aa.bb).thenReturn("zz")
    }

    open class AA(){
        val bb by lazy { "cc" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, `AA.bb` is `final`. `final`/`private`/`equals()`/`hashCode()` methods cannot be stubbed/verified by Mockito. You need to mark `bb` as `open`:

```
open class AA(){
    open val bb by lazy { "cc" }
}
```

You might also consider using [nhaarman/mockito-kotlin: Using Mockito with Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin). e.g.:

```
class GarbTest {
    @Test
    fun xx() {
        val aa = mock<AA>() {
            on { bb } doReturn "zz"
        }
    }

    open class AA() {
        val bb: String = "cc"
    }
}
```